# Average count of characters within a youtube comment

Tags: r

I need to calculate the average number of characters in spam comments and normal comments.

I'm new to R and therefore this question might be an easy one. I received the task to count the average number of characters in spam youtubecomments. I already tried to use the function nchar but I received a counting of 977 and therefore I think I didn't use the correct one. What would be the correct function?

The data set contains many different spamcomments and has the structure as shown in the image.

```
nchar(HAMComments, type = "chars", allowNA = FALSE, keepNA = NA)
```

[image: SPAM Youtube comments strucutre]

I would be very thankful for an answer!

Comment: We can't help you that much without an example. Can you `dput` one of the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Stringr will help:

```
library(stringr)

stringr::str_count(HAMComments)
```

Calculate the mean:

```
mean(stringr::str_count(HAMComments), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Stringr provides a vectorized function to count the letters per comment. Just a little tip: Take care of the encoding, there are some errors.

Comment: Are you assuming HAMComments is a character vector? From the screen shot it looks like the data in a data.frame/tibble in a column called CONTENT. That might be what the problem is.

Comment: His code deals with a character vector. If it´s a data.frame, he can use `stringr::str_count(HAMComments$CONTENT)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I used you're code but received the following error:

argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Therefore I added "as.matrix" and now it worked. But to be honest I don't know what exactly had been changed because of the "as.matrix". Have a great day everyone!

mean(stringr::str_count(as.matrix(SPAMComments)), na.rm = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the problem, something like this should work:

```
df <- data.frame(comment = c("Hi I am a bot", "clau6io_HH is in the house", "stackoverflow"),
                          var2 = 1:3)


nchar(as.character(df$comment))
#> [1] 13 26 13
```